# Skype for Linux Alpha crashes Ubuntu 16 software center

Tags: 16.04, software-center, skype

When I download Skype for Linux Alpha from [here](https://community.skype.com/t5/Linux/Skype-for-Linux-Alpha-and-calling-on-Chrome-amp-Chromebooks/td-p/4434299) and click on it, software center opens and crashes immediately. This does not happen with other .deb files that I have downloaded. Any suggestions?

Comment: Install the deb using dpkg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is common bugs with new software center, as its not dependable yet to install third-party `.deb` files.

Please try install the `.deb` files using `dpkg` instead of software center:

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your/skype.deb
```

Replace `/path/to/your/skype.deb` with your exact path.

Comment: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!